# Genghis admin ui not working with mongodb 3.0.1 wired tiger

Tags: mongodb

We recently updated to mongodb 3.0.1 using the wired tiger storage engine, and have been using the genghis php admin ui through the browser.  However, genghis is not completely working now, specifically it won't show collections available in the database.  It seems the php call $db->listCollections() returns 0 collections.  We are using the latest php mongo driver(1.6.5), and php 5.5.9.

Genghis will show collections for databases if we switch back to the mmap storage engine, so it looks like it might be something going on with how the php driver and listCollections() call works with the wired tiger storage engine?  There are no errors in the apache or mongodb logs when I try browsing the databases with genghis.

I tried searching online and couldn't find any related problems, has anyone had problems with wired tiger + php like this?

Comment: Are you certain you are using the 1.6.5 PHP driver? Can you check via `phpinfo()` to be certain? If the `listCollections()` call isn't working with WiredTiger storage, this usually indicates an older driver that does not support the new `listCollections` server command required for WiredTiger in MongoDB 3.0. I just tried Genghis 2.3.11 with the 1.6.5 PHP driver and it works fine for listing collections with WiredTiger storage.

Comment: I checked `phpinfo()` and `php -i`, both say the mongo php driver is 1.6.5.

Comment: Hrm .. haven't been able to reproduce the issue. What version of Genghis are you running? Can you try to run a standalone test with just $db->listCollections() in a PHP script?

Comment: I'm running the latest genghis, 2.3.11.  I tried running $db->listCollections() in a separate script and it still returns zero collections :\.  I don't know if this will matter, but I dumped the data with `mongodump` from the old mmap database and did a `mongorestore` to import it into the new database running with wired tiger.  I don't know if this could cause a conflict or corruption in data possibly causing the collections to not get found?

Comment: It looks like there's a new version of the mongo php driver out, 1.6.6.  I updated to it and it looks like everything is working now.

Comment: There weren't any [changes in the PHP 1.6.6 driver](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10007&version=15286) that should have affected this, but good to hear you resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest mongo php driver, 1.6.6 fixed it.

`sudo pecl upgrade mongo`